# get post content of particular post by url

Tags: php, posts, rss, curl

I want to get the post content of particular post using Curl or any other methods from third party website

is it possible?

As the structure remains the same `<entry-content>` i guess there should be some way to fetch the data.

Any plugins-suggestion are also welcomed.

Comment: Plugin recommendation is off-topic here.